# Adding text on top of an image carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm looking to get different paragraphs of text to sit on top of slides in a jquery carousel I'm using. The html being used is below;

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide">
            <p>example text to sit on top of carousel and change when you click
            through carousel images</p>
            <img src="library/images/item1.jpg" class="imgdivide">
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <img src="library/images/item2.jpg" class="imgdivide">
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <img src="library/images/item1.jpg" class="imgdivide">
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
            <img src="library/images/item2.jpg" class="imgdivide">
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the styling I have at the moment;

```
.slider {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slides { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide p { 
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    size:16px; 
    line-height: 20px; 
    color: #FFF;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
}
```

If anyone can help out on this that would be ace!

Answer (score 1):

Try your text with a class that has some z-index. like this:

```
    <li class="slide">
        <p class="text-top-image">example text to sit on top of carousel and change when you click
        through carousel images</p>
        <img src="library/images/item1.jpg" class="imgdivide">
    </li>
```

And your css like this:

```
.text-top-image{
    z-index: 100;
}
```